# Capturing groups don't work as expected with Ruby scan method

Tags: ruby, regex

I need to get an array of floats (both positive and negative) from the multiline string. E.g.: `-45.124, 1124.325` etc

Here's what I do:

```
text.scan(/(\+|\-)?\d+(\.\d+)?/)
```

Although it works fine on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/pJ5kZ3/1) (capturing group 0 matches everything I need), it doesn't work in Ruby code.

Any ideas why it's happening and how I can improve that?

Comment: Another great site is [Rubular](http://rubular.com/)

Comment: @onebree thanks for the link! I'll definitely use it for ruby regexes

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See [`scan` documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/String.html#method-i-scan):

> If the pattern contains no groups, each individual result consists of the matched string, `$&`. **If the pattern contains groups, each individual result is itself an array containing one entry per group.**

***You should remove capturing groups (if they are redundant), or make them [non-capturing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-in-regular-expressions) (if you just need to group a sequence of patterns to be able to quantify them), or use extra code/group in case a capturing group cannot be avoided.***

1. In this scenario, the capturing group is used to quantifiy a pattern sequence, thus all you need to do is **convert the capturing group into a non-capturing one** by replacing all unescaped `(` with `(?:` (there is only one occurrence here):

```rb
text = " -45.124, 1124.325"
puts text.scan(/[+-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?/)
```

See [demo](http://ideone.com/8DZdOh), output:

```rb
-45.124
1124.325
```

Well, if you need to also match floats like `.04` you can use `[+-]?\d*\.?\d+`. See [another demo](http://ideone.com/BY0lkl)

2. There are cases when you cannot get rid of a capturing group, e.g. when the regex contains a backreference to a capturing group. In that case, you may either a) declare a variable to store all matches and collect them all inside a `scan` block, or b) enclose the whole pattern with another capturing group and map the results to get the first item from each match, c) you may use a [`gsub`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/String.html#method-i-gsub) with just a regex as a single argument to return an *Enumerator*, with `.to_a` to get the array of matches:

```rb
text = "11234566666678"
# Variant a:
results = []
text.scan(/(\d)\1+/) { results << Regexp.last_match(0) }
p results                              # => ["11", "666666"]
# Variant b:
p text.scan(/((\d)\2+)/).map(&:first)  # => ["11", "666666"]
# Variant c:
p text.gsub(/(\d)\1+/).to_a  # => ["11", "666666"]
```

See [this Ruby demo](https://ideone.com/xmsa6Y).

Comment: That was quite eye-opening. Thanks

Comment: In your case 2 another option is `"11234566666678".gsub(/(\d)\1+/).to_a #=> ["11", "666666"]`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland The more the better. Though the question is about `.scan`, other ways to achieve the same are really welcome.

Answer (score 1):

```
([+-]?\d+\.\d+)
```

assumes there is a leading digit before the decimal point

see [demo at Rubular](http://rubular.com/r/L4dS2fBG4K)

Comment: This regex has one drawback: it matches `4.`, too.

Comment: @stribizhev Well spotted. Updated

Comment: No, now it does not match `1`.

Answer (score 1):

If you need capture groups for a complex pattern match, but want the entire expression returned by `.scan`, this can work for you.

Suppose you want to get the image urls in this string perhaps from a markdown text with html image tags:

```rb
str = %(
Before
<img src="https://images.zenhubusercontent.com/11223344e051aa2c30577d9d17/110459e6-915b-47cd-9d2c-1842z4b73d71">

After
<img src="https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/111222333/75255445-f59fb800-57af-11ea-9b7a-a235b84bf150.png">).strip
```

You may have a regular expression defined to match just the urls, and maybe used a [Rubular example like this](https://rubular.com/r/1n0IFCBC6suEsE) to build/test your `Regexp`

```rb
image_regex = 
  /https\:\/\/(user-)?images.(githubusercontent|zenhubusercontent).com.*\b/
```

Now you don't need each sub-capture group, but just the the entire expression in your your `.scan`, you can just wrap the whole pattern inside a capture group and use it like this:

```rb
image_regex = 
  /(https\:\/\/(user-)?images.(githubusercontent|zenhubusercontent).com.*\b)/

str.scan(image_regex).map(&:first)
=> ["https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/1949900/75255445-f59fb800-57af-11ea-9b7a-e075f55bf150.png",
 "https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/1949900/75255473-02bca700-57b0-11ea-852a-58424698cfb0.png"]
```

#### How does this actually work?

Since you have 3 capture groups, `.scan` alone will return an `Array` of arrays with, one for each capture:

```rb
str.scan(image_regex)
=> [["https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/111222333/75255445-f59fb800-57af-11ea-9b7a-e075f55bf150.png", "user-", "githubusercontent"],
 ["https://images.zenhubusercontent.com/11223344e051aa2c30577d9d17/110459e6-915b-47cd-9d2c-0714c8f76f68", nil, "zenhubusercontent"]]
```

Since we only want the 1st (outter) capture group, we can just call `.map(&:first)`