# Regex fragment for "one or more instances of this pattern"

Tags: regex, ruby

I'm trying to write a regex to scan a codebase to find all instances of a function call, and return a list of the arguments to the function.

The function is called "t" (I know, helpful eh) and it takes a single string which is a mix of lowercase letters (or digits) separated by `.`, eg

```
t('foo.bar.baz')
t("chunky.chicken")
t('red.green.yellow.blue.1.2.3')
```

One immediate problem is to distinguish it from other function calls ending in `t`, but I thought I could do that by preceding the regex with `[^a-z]`, ie "not a letter".

Here's what I have so far, which I thought would work but doesn't, quite:

```
/[^a-z]t\(["']([a-z0-9_]+\.)+[a-z0-9_]+["']\)/

#with my thinking being as follows:
[^a-z] #not a letter
t #the character t
\( #open bracket
["'] #one instance of single or double quote
([a-z0-9_]+\.)+ #one or more instances of mix-of-letters-and-numbers-and-underscores followed by .
[a-z0-9_]+ #mix-of-letters-and-numbers-and-underscores
["'] #one instance of single or double quote
\) #close bracket
```

I'm matching it against this test line:

```
s = "<span style=\"color: #999;font-size: 0.5em;display: block;\"><%= t('cmw.letter.yumu_invite_for') %>:</span> <%= h(pupil.first_name.capitalize) %>"
```

and it's returning `"letter."` whereas i want it to return `" t('cmw.letter.yumu_invite_for')"`

I think the problem is this part:
`([a-z0-9_]+\.)+ #one or more instances of mix-of-letters-and-numbers-and-underscores followed by .`

If i change it so that instead of looking for "one or more instances of this pattern", it's specifically looking for three segments, with . inbetween, then it works:

```
s = "<span style=\"color: #999;font-size: 0.5em;display: block;\"><%= t('cmw.letter.yumu_invite_for') %>:</span> <%= h(pupil.first_name.capitalize) %>"
regex = /[^a-z]t\(["'][a-z0-9_]+\.[a-z0-9_]+\.+[a-z0-9_]+["']\)/
s.scan(regex)
=> [" t('cmw.letter.yumu_invite_for')"]
```

So, I guess that the "multiple instances of this pattern" bit doesn't work like how I think it works?

This is in ruby but I think this might be a more general regex question.

EDIT - I just tried this in javascript and it works:

```
s.match(/[^a-z]t\(["']([a-z0-9_]+\.)+[a-z0-9_]+["']\)/)[0]
" t('cmw.letter.yumu_invite_for')"
```

So actually I think maybe this is a ruby question after all.

Comment: Maybe this one: `\bt\([^)]+\)`?

Comment: Also if you want to use your regex, then you might want to use non-capturing group not to get only one part of the result: `[^a-z]t\(["'](?:[a-z0-9_]+\.)+[a-z0-9_]+["']\)`

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31319160/3832970) will clear it out for you.

Comment: And use `regex = /\bt\(["'][a-z0-9_]+(?:\.[a-z0-9_]+)*["']\)/`

Comment: Just so you're aware - that t() function is very likely a translate function, it means that this application has been localized for more than one language.  So there is a yaml file somewhere (in config/ folder likely) named perhaps en.yml and then es.yml etc, and the key that you're seeing 'chunky.chicken' is the key to the corresponding text in the language file.  This is a common standard for creating a single site that is multi-lingual.  I think that you don't need this regex so much as you need to understand translation in Rails.

Comment: @tgmerritt it is indeed a translation function, and the translations are indeed in yaml.  I'm writing a script to look for all the calls to it in our codebase so that I can identify translation calls to keys that don't exist and, vice versa, which translation keys are not used anywhere.